# making app by clickteam fusion 2.5

Tags: android

Hi I just want it to know is their way I can publish an app from clickteam fusion 2.5 or did anyone else tried.

p.s I know there are website that you have to convert it to keystore and stuff like that but I don't know where to start

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can but you need to have Android exporter by Clickteam for that. You also need to have Java SDK installed which will be used to build your apk files.

To publish your application, make sure you have "Release mode" enabled in the application properties. Also you need to create the keystore with the signing key.

To generate a keystore you can use the Keytool tool provided in the bin directory of the JDK. This is a command line tool. For example, the following command line will generate the "d:\great-release-key.keystore" file that contains the "great_key_name" key:

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore d:\great-release-key.keystore -alias great_key_name -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```

Keytool asks you for your name, organization, country, the keystore password and key password.

All this is quite well documented in Fusion help. Good chapter to read is "Distributing your application/Android"